# D3 V4 how to force Label of stacked bars to visible for small bars? please reply I'm really struggling for it

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3JS and struggling with stacked bar below is my dummy code. I tried adding 10 to data to make it visible and then subtract 10 from label to make the label look correct but this cause problem with yAxis where value of bar is crossing the ticker with less then bar value, for example label was showing 95 but bar crossed 100 ticker coz bar size is 95 + 10 = 105. Help me with this.[In image you can find out small bars label are not visible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>d3.js learning</title>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    svg {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
    }

    path.domain {
      stroke: none;
    }

    .y .tick line {
      stroke: #ddd;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="ashu" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      "health": "JAN",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 1,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 67,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 13,
      "Bank": 15
    }, {
      "health": "FEB",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 60,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 9,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 20,
      "Bank": 5
    }, {
      "health": "MAR",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 40,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 22,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 21,
      "Bank": 99
    }, {
      "health": "APR",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 60,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 1,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 99,
      "Bank": 90
    }, {
      "health": "MAY",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 2,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 27,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 43,
      "Bank": 82
    }, {
      "health": "JUN",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 17,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 52,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 79,
      "Bank": 9
    }, {
      "health": "JUL",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 37,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 24,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 35,
      "Bank": 51
    }, {
      "health": "AUG",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 16,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 17,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 53,
      "Bank": 38
    }, {
      "health": "SEP",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 15,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 32,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 5,
      "Bank": 31
    }];
    let xData = d3.keys(data[0]);
    const yData = xData.shift();
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);


    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 400,
      height = 300,
      padding = 100;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
    var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(6).innerTickSize(-width)
      .tickPadding(10);

    var svg = d3.select("#ashu").append("svg").attr("width",
      "100%").attr("height",
      "100%").append("g").attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
      return data.map(function(d, yData) {
        return {
          x: d[Object.keys(d)[0]],
          y: d[c]
        };
      });
    });

    var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));
    var total = 0;
    var maximumY = d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1], function(d) {
      return (d.y + d.y0);
    });
    y.domain([-(maximumY * .02), maximumY]).nice();

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
      .append("g").attr("class", "stack").style("fill",
        function(d, i) {
          return color(i);
        });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html("Total : " + (d.y + d.y0))
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });

    layer.selectAll("text")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        let r = ((d.y < 10) ? (d.y - 10) : d.y);
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return x(d.x) + 15;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0);
      })
      .attr("dy", "-0.15em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "black");


    svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
      "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").attr("transform", "translate(0,0)").call(y_axis);


    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + Math.abs((i - 8) * 20) + ")";
      });

    legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width + 10)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 32)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return xData[i];
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit your code please.

Comment: did it please help @Wandrille

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the labels are being hidden due the order in which the g elements are creating in the DOM, in that elements created later will overlap elements created earlier.  This means that the INSOLVENCIES group labels will be hidden by the orange rects for the SPV/ASSETBACKED.

A solution would be to create new g element for your labels, so they always appear on top of your rects. See the snippet below.

Now, where you have small values, there will always be a challenge about where to position the labels.  The snippet places them in the middle of the bar, but you may need to play around with that

```js
var data = [{
      "health": "JAN",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 1,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 67,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 13,
      "Bank": 15
    }, {
      "health": "FEB",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 60,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 9,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 20,
      "Bank": 5
    }, {
      "health": "MAR",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 40,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 22,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 21,
      "Bank": 99
    }, {
      "health": "APR",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 60,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 1,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 99,
      "Bank": 90
    }, {
      "health": "MAY",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 2,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 27,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 43,
      "Bank": 82
    }, {
      "health": "JUN",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 17,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 52,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 79,
      "Bank": 9
    }, {
      "health": "JUL",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 37,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 24,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 35,
      "Bank": 51
    }, {
      "health": "AUG",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 16,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 17,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 53,
      "Bank": 38
    }, {
      "health": "SEP",
      "INSOLVENCIES": 15,
      "SPV/ASSETBACKED": 32,
      "OPERATINGCOMPANIES": 5,
      "Bank": 31
    }];
    let xData = d3.keys(data[0]);
    const yData = xData.shift();
    var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);


    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 400,
      height = 300,
      padding = 100;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
    var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(6).innerTickSize(-width)
      .tickPadding(10);

    var svg = d3.select("#ashu").append("svg").attr("width",
      "100%").attr("height",
      "100%").append("g").attr(
      "transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function(c) {
      return data.map(function(d, yData) {
        return {
          x: d[Object.keys(d)[0]],
          y: d[c]
        };
      });
    });

    var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);
    
    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));
    var total = 0;
    var maximumY = d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1], function(d) {
      return (d.y + d.y0);
    });
    y.domain([0, maximumY]).nice();

    var layer1 = svg.selectAll(".stack1").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
      .append("g").attr("class", "stack").style("fill",
        function(d, i) {
          return color(i);
        });
    
    var layer2 = svg.selectAll(".stack2").data(dataStackLayout).enter()
      .append("g")
     .attr("class", "stack")
      .style("fill", "black");

    layer1.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);
        div.html("Total : " + (d.y + d.y0))
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });

    layer2.selectAll("text")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return x(d.x) + (x.rangeBand())/2;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0 + (d.y/2));
      })
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("fill", "black");


    svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
      "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").attr("transform", "translate(0,0)").call(y_axis);


    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + Math.abs((i - 8) * 20) + ")";
      });

    legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width + 10)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 32)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return xData[i];
      });
```

```css
svg {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
    }

    path.domain {
      stroke: none;
    }

    .y .tick line {
      stroke: #ddd;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="ashu" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @tom you saved my day. can we add background to these text which make it more visible??